# java.RMI socket creation details?

Tags: java, sockets, rmi, rmiregistry

i've looked at doc, tested, debugged ... but remain stumped.  time for stackOverflow!  i'll set the stage, then describe my error.

**Background**

i have an RMI client/sever setup that works fine when client, server and rmiregistry
all live together on localhost.  so then i fire up rmiregistry on serverHost, with rmi.server.logCalls trace turned on (called RegistryTrace below).   the important parts of the server code:

```
String hostname = "//serverHost.local/project"
String codeBase = "file:/home/rik/Code/eclipse/project/bin/"

System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", hostname);
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.codebase", codeBase); 

Driver server = new Driver();
Naming.rebind(hostname, server);
```

when i start the server, i see the rebind() call succeeds (by looking at RegistryTrace).  also, looking at the list generated by Naming.list() shows it contains "//serverHost.local:1099/project"

starting my client, it successfully completes Naming.lookup():

```
server = (ServerInterface)Naming.lookup(serverHost);
```

looking at RegistryTrace, i am able to confirm that this lookup() query gets to the server end.

**Error on first RMI**

but now: my next statement tries to call one of server's methods

```
boolean status = server.initConnection(username);
```

generates an IllegalArgumentException:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = socket host = null
at sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector.select(DefaultProxySelector.java:151)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:424)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:22)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:128)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:595)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:198)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:184)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:110)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:178)
at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:132)
at $Proxy0.initConnection(Unknown Source)
at project.client.View2.main(View2.java:651)
```

i've traced this down into Java source to a call to java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod()

```
   private Object invokeRemoteMethod(Object proxy,
                  Method method,
                  Object[] args)
throws Exception
{
try {
    if (!(proxy instanceof Remote)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "proxy not Remote instance");
    }

    // EXCEPTION OCCURS WITHIN CALL TO ref.invoke() BELOW
    //
    return ref.invoke((Remote) proxy, method, args,
              getMethodHash(method));

} catch (Exception e) {
    if (!(e instanceof RuntimeException)) {
    Class<?> cl = proxy.getClass();
    try {
        method = cl.getMethod(method.getName(),
                  method.getParameterTypes());
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
        throw (IllegalArgumentException)
        new IllegalArgumentException().initCause(nsme);
    }
    Class<?> thrownType = e.getClass();
    for (Class<?> declaredType : method.getExceptionTypes()) {
        if (declaredType.isAssignableFrom(thrownType)) {
        throw e;
        }
    }
    e = new UnexpectedException("unexpected exception", e);
    }
    throw e;
}
}
```

then i lose it in the source trace.  (anyone know the story about source availability for things like sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef ?)  the rest of the trace makes it seem like RMI can't create a socket?

i'm sure many parts of this code could be cleaner; any suggestions appreciated.  i also need to convert this into jar file distributions, so if specifying them now for java.rmi.server.codebase would be easier...?

thanks for any suggestions,  rik

Comment: http://jdk7src.sourceforge.net/ provides a src-jdk.zip that contains almost all classes included in Oracle JDK 7 (all that are identical in OpenJDK7). For JDK 6 you'll have to get the JRL source (after accepting the JRL) and copy them together yourself...

Comment: thanks for the pointer to the jdk7src at sourceforge, mihi.  but i've poked thru [link]SE6 download(http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u30-download-1377139.html) and also the  at [link]archives(http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jdk-6u29-oth-JPR) but don't find source there?

Comment: http://download.java.net/jdk6/source/ is the latest "official" JRL source for Java 6. For later versions, just start at e.g. http://download.java.net/jdk6/6u30/ and click through the file structure until you find it :D

Answer (score 0):

It is constructing a SocksSocketImpl so you must be specifying an invalid SOCKS proxy host or port via socks.proxyHost/socks.proxyPort at the client, or perhaps you have java.rmi.server.hostname set to a strange value at the server.

Comment: thanks EJP!  but how could it be that the Naming.lookup() call, using the same hostname, is working?  doesn't it use the same value as the RMI's?

Comment: @rikb It uses whatever you tell it to use in the lookup URL. When you call the remote method it uses whatever the server put into the stub, which is influenced by java.rmi.server.hostname.

Comment: using Naming.list() shows that it's constructed "//serverHost.local:1099/project", which seems correct?

Comment: @riukb Yes but why are we concentrating on the lookup, which is working?

Comment: thanks or staying with me on this @EJP.  i am thinking the Naming.lookup() **establishes** the same socket that is subsequently  used to serve the RMI calls; not true?

Comment: and the fact that Naming.list() on the server gets this (good?) URL for itself from the rmiregistry makes me think the RMI call should go through for the client?

Comment: @rikb Not true. `Naming.lookup()` gives you a remote stub, which contains an IP:port, which is used to form another connection. Consider that the `RMIRegistry` can use a different port and indeed run in a different process from your remote object. No way to reuse a connection there. The fact that `Naming.list()` and `Naming.lookup()` work just indicate (a) that your lookup/list URL is correct and (b) there is something bound in the registry. It doesn't have anything to do with connecting to the remote object itself.